# Make read more link open on separate page in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I am using joomla 2.5. When creating an article I add read more links to it. The issue I am having is, when a page has a single article then the read more link overwrites that content with the new article. I want the read more link to open as a separate page. I want it to be dynamic and not manually change.

Any thing I am missing ? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Yes you got it right sir, I am talking about the display or menu type "Single article". Sorry about not being clear

Comment: Thanks, now... how are you adding read more links to an article that you are already viewing ? I don't get the idea. When you create the article, do you insert the read more link located under the wysiwyg editor ? and then what do you see on the frontend when you go to that article ?

Comment: After adding the read more link. I have a Newsflash module to view list of news, which has read more links to it. Now when I click read more then it refreshes the page and replaces the article on that page with the news I clicked on. Does that make sense ?

Comment: No problem sir, Name of the module is newsflash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if you sorted it out but I think I know what you mean.

You may need to create a new Menu and use it as a hidden menu

so to have your articles open in a separate page or its own page create a hidden menu.

1 - Go to Menu
2 - click Menus tab next to Menu Items
3 - click new
4 - give it a Title example Hidden Menu
5 - fill out Menu type example Hidden
6 - Description optional

in this new menu you created you want to create a menu item

depending on where your articles are stored will depend on your menu item

lets say your articles are in a category named news

make a new Menu Item, call it what you want

then in menu item type select Category Blog and in the Required Settings choose your category...

save your menu item...

that should do what you want...

so in your main menu you have an article that is in the news category when you click on it. the article should open in the same window by itself...

excuse any spelling mistakes found...

Answer (score 0):

I went through the Newsflash module options and the source code as well, unfortunately the module will always open the links on the same window.

You will need to override the layout to modify this behavior.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

This is the file that you need to 'clone' in your template folder as explained in the link above:

> modules/mod_articles_news/tmpl/_item.php

Finally, in the new file modify the line 16 to this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $item->link;?>" target="_blank">
```

and then the line 34

```
echo '<a class="readmore" href="'.$item->link.'" target="_blank">'.$item->linkText.'</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this sir, but wouldn't this open in a new tab as well ?

Comment: It will open in a new window OR in a new tab. I think it depends on the user's browser settings.

Comment: I do not want a new window or a tab, Is it possible to have it in the current window but different page sir ?

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. I'm sorry.

Comment: I understand the question, I got the same problem. If you look at "modules" there is an option to set on which pages to display the module. These pages are menu items. If you click on "read more" it renders content on "homepage" menu item, with all the modules from homepage. That's how newsflash behave.