# Joomla Article to open in a new page instead of home page

Tags: joomla3.0

I am using joomla 3.5 and in my home page i added articles with read more option. Whenever i am clicking the read more option it opens in the home page but i want it to open  in a new page instead of the home page. How to do so.
thanks is advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may require editing the core Joomla files of your site.

Go to components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php or whatever type it is and change:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
```

TO:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank">
```

You should also change it in components/com_content/views/featured/tmpl/default_item.php

Also you can try a menu item for the category the articles belong to. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969320/make-read-more-link-open-on-separate-page-in-joomla) here

Answer (score 0):

You can try editing the target window in the Menu Manager under details tab

in the options you can select 3 options

- Parent
- New Window with navigation
- New window without navigation

you can try choosing the 2 options next to parent for it to redirect to a new page